# Structuremap 3 multiple decoration

Tags: c#, structuremap, structuremap3

I am trying to create a dependency graph in StructureMap 3 with a chain of decorators:

Each instance has a constructor with multiple arugments, but exactly one argument of an inner IGeocoder, e.g.

```
public SomeCachingGeocoder(IGeoCoder inner, IFoo somethingElse)
```

I am hooking them up like this:

```
For<OviGeoCoder>().Use<OviGeoCoder>();
For<SqlCachingGeocoder>().Use<SqlCachingGeocoder>().Ctor<IGeoCoder>().Is<OviGeoCoder>();
For<RedisCachingGeocoder>().Use<RedisCachingGeocoder>().Ctor<IGeoCoder>().Is<SqlCachingGeocoder>();
For<IGeoCoder>().Use<RedisCachingGeocoder>();
```

But I get

> Bi-directional dependency relationship detected! Check the StructureMap stacktrace below:
>   1.) Instance of SOAM.Services.IGeoCoder (SOAM.Services.Geocoding.RedisCachingGeocoder)
>   2.) new RedisCachingGeocoder(*Default of IDatabase*, *Default of IGeoCoder*)
>   3.) SOAM.Services.Geocoding.RedisCachingGeocoder
>   4.) Instance of SOAM.Services.IGeoCoder (SOAM.Services.Geocoding.RedisCachingGeocoder)
>   5.) new HomeController(*Default of IGeoCoder*, *Default of IAlertService*)
>   6.) SOAM.Web.Controllers.HomeController
>   7.) Instance of SOAM.Web.Controllers.HomeController
>   8.) Container.GetInstance(SOAM.Web.Controllers.HomeController)

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you use the `DecorateAllWith` method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25136317/264697)?

Comment: I dont want to decorate all instances with a specific decorator, i want to decorate A with B, B with C and C with D etc. DecorateWith also doesnt (as far as I could see) allow for injection; you need to create the instance yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DecorateAllWith` allows auto-wiring by default and allows stacking decorators in a quite easy way:

```
For<IGeoCoder>().Use<OviGeoCoder>();
For(typeof(IGeoCoder)).DecorateAllWith(typeof(SqlCachingGeocoder));
For(typeof(IGeoCoder)).DecorateAllWith(typeof(RedisCachingGeocoder));
```

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you cannot use *DecorateAllWith()* then this should work:

```
        var container = new Container(
            c =>
                {
                    c.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
                    c.For<IGeoCoder>().Add<OviGeoCoder>().Named("default");
                    c.For<IGeoCoder>()
                        .Add<SqlCachingGeocoder>()
                        .Ctor<IGeoCoder>()
                        .Is(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<IGeoCoder>("default"))
                        .Named("SqlCaching");
                    c.For<IGeoCoder>()
                        .Use<RedisCachingGeocoder>()
                        .Ctor<IGeoCoder>()
                        .Is(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<IGeoCoder>("SqlCaching"));
                });
```

Wanna find what's the difference when using *Use* vs *Add*? [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27365025/4336786)