# How decorate in structuremap?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I try it decorate IProjectService but I can't find documentation for struturemap

```
For<IProjectService>().Use<ProjectServiceLogDecorator>();
For<IProjectService>().Use<ProjectService>()
                      .DecorateWith((context, decorator) =>   
                                  context.GetInstance<ProjectServiceLogDecorator>());
```

What I do wrong?

exeption:

> Bi-directional dependency relationship detected! Check the
>   StructureMap stacktrace below:
>   1.) new ProjectServiceLogDecorator(*Default of IRepository*, *Default of IUnitOfWork*, *Default of IProjectService*, *Default of IPrincipal*, *Default of AuditEventLogger*)
>   2.) Project.Services.Projects.ProjectServiceLogDecorator
>   3.) Instance of Project.Services.Projects.ProjectServiceLogDecorator
>   4.) FuncInterceptor of Project.Services.Projects.IProjectService: IContext.GetInstance()
>   5.) Project.Services.Projects.ProjectService
>   6.) Instance of Project.Services.Projects.IProjectService (Project.Services.Projects.ProjectService)
>   7.) new UsersController(*Default of IUserService*, *Default of IService*, *Default of IUserNotificationService*,
>   *Default of IService*, *Default of IProjectService*, *Default of ILicenseGroupService*)
>   8.) Project.Web.Api.Controllers.UsersController
>   9.) Instance of Project.Web.Api.Controllers.UsersController
>   10.) Container.GetInstance(Project.Web.Api.Controllers.UsersController)

I found solution but it is **disgustingly**:

```
For<IProjectService>().Use<ProjectService>().DecorateWith((ctx, service) => 
    new ProjectServiceLogDecorator(
        ctx.GetInstance<IRepository<Project>>(),
        ctx.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>(),
        service,
        ctx.GetInstance<ILicenseService>(),
        ctx.GetInstance<IPrincipal>(),
        ctx.GetInstance<AuditEventLogger>()
    )
);
```

Comment: I think you need `DecorateAllWith`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134096/structuremap3-decorateallwith

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although there is [no documentation yet](http://structuremap.github.io/interception-and-decorators/), there are a complete set of [unit tests](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap.Testing/Acceptance/interception_acceptance_tests.cs#L81) showing all of the different ways you can configure a decorator pattern. I believe the one you want is:

```
For<IProjectService>().DecorateAllWith<ProjectServiceLogDecorator>();
For<IProjectService>().Use<ProjectService>();
```

You can add additional decorators simply by doing the following. However, note that the outermost decorator is the last `.DecorateAllWith` specified, so it might be more intuitive to specify the innermost class first.

```
For<IProjectService>().Use<ProjectService>();
For<IProjectService>().DecorateAllWith<ProjectServiceLogDecorator>();
For<IProjectService>().DecorateAllWith<SomeOtherDecorator>();
```

Which results in:

```
SomeOtherDecorator
    ProjectServiceLogDecorator
        ProjectService
```

If you need more control than that, you can always use smart instances to apply the constructor parameters to the decorator explicitly (without needing to supply all parameters explicitly).

```
var projectService = For<IProjectService>().Use<ProjectService>();
For<IProjectService>().Use<ProjectServiceLogDecorator>()
    .Ctor<IProjectService>().Is(projectService);
```